# h:inputText does not fire ajax change event when changing its value from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I have an input text field that changes its value in a javascript function when *keyup* event is fired and a f:ajax that should fire for the *change* event:

```
<h:inputText ... onkeyup="functionThantChangesTextValue(this);">
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{someExpensiveCall()}".../>
</h:inputText>
```

The problem is that if I change programatically the value of the inputText in the javascript *functionThantChangesTextValue*, than the ajax does not trigger for the *change* event

I have tried this:

```
function functionThantChangesTextValue(field) {
    ...
    field.value = finalValue;
    field.onchange();
}
```

and in this case the ajax event triggers fine, but I would not really want this to happen immediately after changing the value.
What I really want, is the execute the ajax when changing the value and when loosing the focus.

Comment: *"when loosing the focus"* Is the `blur` event suitable?

Comment: Yes, I used `blur` combined with `focus` event to get it work, see the answer. The problem is that if you change the value of the input field programatically using javascript, the `change` event won't trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to find some sort of solution using `blur` & `focus` events.
On the `focus` event I store the old inputTextValue value using `storeOldValue` function and then I execute the `someExpensiveCall` on the `blur` event only if the current input text value is different from the old one. In this way I try to simulate a `change` event..

```
<h:inputText ... onkeyup="functionThantChangesTextValue(this);">
    <f:ajax event="focus" listener="#{storeOldValue()}"/>
    <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{someExpensiveCall()}".../>
</h:inputText>
```